# Azure Virtual Network Slow downloads from google servers

Tags: azure, google, azure-networking, virtual-network

Whenever i download an image from a google server it is way slower than other images (can take up to 4 seconds)

```
time curl -s https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/og_image.jpg -o image.png
```

real    0m1.656s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.096s

Other server on azure on a different Virtual Network

```
time curl -s https://pay.google.com/about/static/images/social/og_image.jpg -o image.png
```

real    0m0.222s
user    0m0.077s
sys     0m0.058s

What settings of the Virtual network can cause this to be different?

Answer (score 0):

I found one of the issues: on the fast vm the url is resolving to 74.125.143.92
and the slow vm is resolving to 172.217.194.92.
For some reason it's resolving to an ip with 300ms latency.

How is that happening?

EDIT: Found out it's because of AZURE DNS SERVERS. the slow vm's virtual network uses internal azure dns servers which returns that ip. Our vm's are based in the west-europe region. I assume google returns an ip depending on the azure dns server and maybe assumes it's from the american region.